# moving columns from left to right on homescreen

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I'm working on magento and I want the categories that appear on left to be appeared on right side. I tried many tutorial, but didnt get it. Please help me on this. I'm new to magento. Thanks.

Comment: That is b/c the layout for the catalog pages are set to `2columns-left.phtml`. You will need to change that to reflect what you are wanting to do. For example: `2columns-right.phtml`. This all depends on what you have set for the `catalog.xml` or maybe in the `local.xml` file. It also depends on your layouts located in the `page` folder.

Answer (score 1):

To add categories into the sidebar firstly go to:

`app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/navigation`

and create a `.phtml`  file, for example: `left-nav.phtml`

In `left-nav.phtml put this:`

```
<div class="category-nav">       
  <div class="block-content">
                <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></p>
    <ul id="nav_category" class="nav_category">
                <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories(true) as $_category): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This just loops through all the enabled categories and outputs them into a list.

Now you need to link up the list so firstly go into `/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/sbs/layout/page.xml`

Find the bit for 2columns-left, or right if you want it to output on the right. In the layout you are using find:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
```

Inside the block add a line of code like this:

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.listing" as="left_nav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
```

The `before=”-“` just adds it before everything else.

Finally go into:

`/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/page/2columns-left.phtml` and add:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left_nav') ?>
```

Note:

You will need to clean the cache for this to work.

I have written a more in depth answer on my website http://brideo.co.uk/moving-categories-to-left-collumn-magento/